# issue with new create dbcontext class object in asp.net core 2.1

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I m new in .net core 2.1

I m working with .net core 2.1 with code first approach

issue is when I create a new object dbcontext class then give error see below line

```
dbcontextstudent db=new dbcontextstudent();  //here give an red line
```

appsettings.json

```
 },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "sqlserverconn": "Server=DEVISSHAHID; Database=studdbs; User id=xxxx;Password=xxxxx;"
  },
```

Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //connection string
            services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlserverconn")));
```

student.cs

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class student
    {
        [Key]
        public int studid { get; set; }

        public string studname { get; set; }

        public string studsalary { get; set; }

        public int studage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

dbcontextstudent.cs

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class dbcontextstudent : DbContext
    {
        public dbcontextstudent(DbContextOptions<dbcontextstudent> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<student> stud { get; set; }
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

[image]

**I m not understood the above intellisense**

I write the code as per intellisense but still give an error **I know error is clear but not solved**

which place doing I m wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to pass your `DbContext` type to the `AddDbContext` method in `ConfigureServices` method like this:

```
            services.AddDbContext<dbcontextstudent>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlserverconn")));
```

After that, you have registered the `dbcontextstudent` class in dependency injection.

You shouldn't create the instance of `dbcontextstudent`  on your own like you did:

```
dbcontextstudent db=new dbcontextstudent();
```

Instead you can inject it though the constructor of your controller like this:

```
public HomeController : Controller 
{
   private readonly dbcontextstudent _db;

   public HomeController(dbcontextstudent db)
   {
     _db = db;
    }

... and then you can use the _db variable in your post action
}
```

Comment: still I facing dbcontext error  https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7P3c.png

Comment: I updated my answer, both the `HomeController` and `ConfgureServices` needs adjustments

Comment: please can u help more i m facing one error https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY9Fs.png please help

Comment: can you start a new question for this? it's a separate issue

Comment: error is solved just add this line in context class ```Database.EnsureCreated();``` thanks for your time